# Simple Hierarchical select drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i was created select hierarchy ( taxonomy with 3 level), but in default it's show only one level , how i can display all 3 level in default page?  : 
-Any-  + -Any- + -Any- 
I do not want it automatically generates other fields! I want to display by default all the select input
[image]

Comment: Just to double check. Which module you're using: [SHS](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) or [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)? The question how to configure modules should be asked at [Drupal SE](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/), if it's programming question, then it's perfectly fine here.

Comment: im using SHS ,  also Hierarchical Select has the same problem, i want just showin in default all level

Comment: Follow-up: [How can I display all levels in Simple hierarchical select](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/159908/1908) at Drupal SE

Comment: that's my post ! someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Simple Hierarchical select works on the basis of taxonomy term hierarchical structure, meaning consider you selected a term which has child in first drop down. As soon as you select term which has a child term, another drop down box will appear and if you select a term within that box which has another child term in-turn then another drop down will appear. This process continues to any deeper level. So displaying all drop down box by default is not possible as it depends upon user selection in first drop down.

In your case, as far as attached screen shot considered, first drop down's default value is 'none' and as you know 'none' value wont have any child item. So no default display of all drop down.

If you want you could do this, go to your Content Type's 'Manage Fields' section and edit Simple Hierarchical Select field and select default value which has child terms other than none.